# Deploying files inside WPRESOURCES using WSPBuilder

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, wspbuilder, sharepoint-deployment

How can I deploy files in the 'wpresources' folder using SharePoint wsp package built by wspbuilder? 'wpresources' is outside 12 hive (or 14 hive). So how can I copy files outside the SharePoint hive?

Answer (score -1):

You can mapped those folder inside visual studio project ans feature will automatically copy those files to specified folder.

Or

Create module through visual studio and specify the path of the wpresources in xml.